# Mac = itemvalue.substring(itemvalue.length() - 17)

Tags: android, bluetooth, send, connectivity

I want to make connection between my own android device and the selected Bluetooth device which i get after scanning ... but i don't know how this line of code work to get MAC address of selected device ...

String Mac = string.substring(itemvalue.length() - 17);

Whole code of select item from the list is here :

```
unpairlv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()                     {     @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                            String itemValue = (String) unpairlv.getItemAtPosition(position);
                            String MAC = itemValue.substring(itemValue.length() - 17);
                            BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(MAC);
                            // Initiate a connection request in a separate thread
                            ConnectingThread t = new ConnectingThread(bluetoothDevice);
                            t.start();
                        }
                    });
```

and here is my ConnectingThread class :

```
private class ConnectingThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice;

        public ConnectingThread(BluetoothDevice device) {

            BluetoothSocket temp = null;
            bluetoothDevice = device;

            // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                temp = bluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            bluetoothSocket = temp;
        }

        public void run() {
            // Cancel discovery as it will slow down the connection
            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            try {
                // This will block until it succeeds in connecting to the device
                // through the bluetoothSocket or throws an exception
                bluetoothSocket.connect();
            } catch (IOException connectException) {
                connectException.printStackTrace();
                try {
                    bluetoothSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException closeException) {
                    closeException.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            // Code to manage the connection in a separate thread
            /*
               manageBluetoothConnection(bluetoothSocket);
            */
        }

        // Cancel an open connection and terminate the thread
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                bluetoothSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please debug and have a look at where `itemValue` comes from and what it's value is. It's likely to be a string with garbage at the front - so the line you're unsure of it taking the remainder of it which actually contains a valid Mac address. It's likely the string is something like `Physical Adapter Address: <mac address>" and it is stripping the descriptor at the start.

Comment: itemvalue is getting the name of device which i have clicked ...

Comment: By any chance, are the last 16 characters of `itemValue` the Mac Address? If so, the line you're after is just taking that part out as a substring - as mentioned above. If it's not, that's what the code is expecting to be provided - so your problem is in there.

Comment: there is only name of the selected device nothing else ...

Comment: and debugger is not showing the MAC address if it gets ... because i am checking the LogCat to show the value of MAC ...

Comment: If only the name of the selected device is in the string `itemValue`, that's your problem. The line `String MAC = ...` is expecting to get a string with the MAC as the last 16 characters. Why this is the case I can't answer, but at least you now know what the issue is.